# The meaning of "next over" in "In the next room over"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the movie "Extremely Wicked, Shockingly Evil, and Vile" (2019) Florida Prosecutor Larry Simpson tells the jury the following:

"In the next room over, another young woman was lying face down in her own blood."

What does "next over mean? I was not able to find a similar example in [this search] (https://www.google.com/search?q=next+over&oq=next+over+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i60l2.4043j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Thank you!

Comment: The preposition ***over*** is completely optional / unnecessary in your cited context, and whether it's present or not has ***no effect*** on the "meaning". So you may as well just ignore it. If you *insist* on ascribing "meaning", you could say it's intended to amplify the sense of ***away, at some distance, not "here"***.

Comment: ...your Google search wasn't very well designed. I can find many ***written*** examples in Google Books of the sequence [**"in the next room over"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+the+next+room+over%22). There's no good reason for choosing your particularly unpleasant "cited usage" here.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I suspect the reason for choosing that example is because that is the place where the OP actually encountered the phrase themselves, in which case, it is a perfectly good reason for using it (and arguably the best choice).  I will admit the OP included more than was really necesary, but often it is difficult for posters to tell what is relevant and what isn't, so I think this may be understandable.

Comment: In this quote, "next room over" means adjacent.  In other words, things were fine in one room while something horrible was knowable in the room next door.

Comment: @Foogod: So vote to roll back my edit, if that's what you think. I think this question is (still) complete garbage.

Comment: I think your edit was fine and appropriate.  I was just saying I can understand why the OP probably did what they did and I don't think it should be taken as deliberately egregious.

Comment: Would you guys please stop answering questions in comments?

Comment: "The next room" could possibly mean "the next room on the list" or "the next room we entered". "Next room over" is unambiguously a reference to physical proximity. So, I think "over" can add something.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for similar sentences, it is a good idea to first try the *exact* phrase you're looking for, without modifying it.  If I do a Google search for "next room over" (instead of "next over"), it comes up with quite a number of examples.  The problem is that you modified the phrase in a way that changes it into something people don't say.

In this case, "over" is added to emphasize that something is physically neighboring or right next to something else.  "next room" could mean the next room in a sequence, etc (for example, if people were going from room to room, the "next room" might be the next one that they go to, even if that's not physically right next door), but "next room over" strongly implies that the room in question is physically side-by-side with the current one (probably sharing a wall).

This use of "over" with "next" doesn't just apply to rooms.  It can also be used with all kinds of other things to imply the same thing (that they're physically side-by-side), but it's always in the form "next *(noun)* over", never "next over".

Answer (score 0):

*Next room over* means

- something like a barrier or significant distance separates this room and the next room
- there's some unidirectional construct exists where *next* makes sense.

In the floors of many hotels, you can consider the elevator the "starting point" and then go down hallways.  While some hotels have connected halls that lead back to the elevator, others simply go to an exit stair or dead end.

Also in many hotels, the doors to two rooms are next to each other, then a distance or barrier separates them to the next set of two doors.

So by saying "next room over" we usually mean:

- going away from any elevator or entry into the floor
- not the door next to mine, but the one on the next set of doors further away from the elevator.

Here's an extremely crappy MS paint diagram to illustrate (complete with misspellings which I'll fix later.)

[image]

If you were in room 203, your next room would be 204, and your "next room over" could be 205.

The red lins show where you might use "over" to qualify which room you mean.